# In Tomcat 7 do you need to copy context.xml into conf/Catalina/locahost for it to take effect

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Just moved from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 and noticed that when you deploy a webapp called widget the META-INF/context.xml no longer get copied to conf/Catalina/localhost/widget.xml.

What Im unclear about is whether it needs to be, will the settings in context.xml be used if left in META-INF or do they only have effect if moved to conf/Catalina/localhost/widget.xml

Im using a vanilla tomcat 7 installation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) (my emphasis):

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In an individual file at `/META-INF/context.xml` inside the application
>     files. Optionally (**based on the Host's `copyXML` attribute**) this may be
>     copied to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and renamed to
>     application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

The documentation for [Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) has this to say on `copyXML`:

> Set to true if you want a context XML descriptor embedded inside the
>   application (located at `/META-INF/context.xml`) to be copied to xmlBase
>   when the application is deployed. **On subsequent starts, the copied
>   context XML descriptor will be used in preference to any context XML
>   descriptor embedded inside the application even if the descriptor
>   embedded inside the application is more recent.** The flag's value
>   defaults to false. Note if deployXML is false, this attribute will
>   have no effect.

Comment: I should have said Ive already looked at this and noticed the copyXML attribute, but this doesn't answer my question. To reiterate if I just leave the context.xml in META-INF is it used, or does it only have any effect if it is renamed and copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/

Comment: Yes it does. It says right before the part I quoted "Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:". If it can "be defined in an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml", obviously Tomcat will pick it up. The copying under $CATALINA_BASE/conf is just so you can see all the configurations grouped in the same place. Besides, didn't you try?

Comment: More documentation: copyXML is actually used to bootstrap the configuration under $CATALINA_BASE/conf, which is the one used on subsequent restarts.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice your emphasis. I didn't want to bore you with the details, but widget.war and widget2.war both had there context.xml copied into conf, but at some point one of these went missing yet they both still worked so I wasn't sure if it worked because of the presence of context.xml or if widget2.xml had been copied to some work directory.

Comment: FWIW I cannot see that having these contexts in conf is terribly useful, I guess that is why copyXML is now false by default.

Comment: In response to Paul's last comment about not seeing the benefit of having the contexts in the conf, I've found it useful for things like JNDI data sources, where you build a war once, and then deploy the same war to test and production environments. You can then modify the context file in conf safe in the knowledge that next time you deploy, your changes won't be overwritten. Granted, you could build separate wars for each environment each time but they you have to manage the various configurations.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the context.xml in META-INF is used unless the  element deployXML is set to `false`. Note from the [Tomcat 7 docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation), the default is `true` unless a security manager is enabled!

However, from the docs, I was under the impression that setting the `copyXML` attribute in the context.xml itself (without touching server.xml) would cause the file to be copied to conf:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/widget" copyXML="true" />
```

However, using Tomcat 7, it seems that the file doesn't get copied to conf unless the `copyXML` is set to `true` on the  as Frank answered above.